# Cucumber sandwich jar keeps on listening and not generating the reports on jenkins slave

Tags: java, jar, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-java

Below are the commands that I am using in the **Jenkins** build--> Execute Shell configuration

1) `git config --local user.name XXXXX`

2) `curl -o cucumber-sandwich.jar -Lk "path to download cucumber sandwich jar"`

3)

```
nohup java -jar cucumber-sandwich.jar & 
/opt/beasys/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn -f myProject/pom.xml -s settings.xml -Ptest -Dit.test=myproject clean verify
```

4) `nohup java -jar cucumber-sandwich.jar -f /opt/jenkins/ws/myProject/target/TestResults/json -o /opt/jenkins/ws/myProject/CucumberReports/cucumber-sandwich`

Locally the reports are getting generated(feature_overview.html etc) but not on jenkins server.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this is because you need the -n flag to your step #3 to get the report to stop generating after 1 test run; however I would strogly recommend using the cucumber jenkins plugin and follow the steps here: http://moduscreate.com/integrating-bdd-cucumber-test-suites-jenkins-3-steps/